# I misstyped git remote add

Tags: git, git-remote

I misstyped "git remote add origin ...".

Actually, i typed "git remote add orginin".
How can i change it back to origin ?

I rather not delete my local repository, if i can just change orginin to origin it would be perfect.

I checked with `git remote -v`.

I got `orginin ssh://git@...git (fetch)`

`orginin ssh://git@... (push)`

I tried `git remote set-url origin git://newurl`
-> `error: No such remote 'origin.`

Comment: `git remote rename blahblah origin` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to eftshift0, the command `git remote rename orginin origin` fixed it.